# Redirect to other page after logging in or out without loosing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Basically, I just need redirect the user to index page after logging in or out without loosing state.
In my main.js:

```
render() {
   return(
      <div id="main">
         <Router>
            <Menu />
            <Switch>
               <Route exact path='/' component={Home}>
               <Route exact path='/about' component={About}>
               <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact}>
            </Switch>
         </Router>
      </div>
   )
}
```

menu.js:

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'
constructor() {
   super()
   this.state = {
      login: false
   }
   this.onLogin = this.onLogin.bind(this)
}

onLogin() {
   ...some declarations and states
   this.setState({login: true})
}

render(){
   if (this.state.login === true) {
      return <Redirect to='/'>
   }
   return(
      <div>
         <LoggedOut onLogin={this.onLogin}/>
         <LoggedIn />
      </div>
   )
}
```

loggedout.js

```
render(){
   return(
      <div>
         <button onClick={this.props.onLogin}>Log-In</button
      </div>
   )
}
```

The Redirect works but I loose the states that keeps that user in the state of login. I've tried { browserHistory } but gives the same result.  I've tried history.push('/') but I must've missing something and I always loose all the states. I'm a ReactJs newbie and I really need your help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best pattern to apply here is using the React context api. When using this api you can acces the loggedIn state every where you want in the app.

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

const AuthContext = createContext({
  loggedIn: null,
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {}
});

export default AuthContext;
```

```
function App() {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  const login = () => {
    setLoggedIn(true);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setLoggedIn(false);
  };

  return (
    <div id="main">
       <Router>
         <AuthContext.Provider value={{ loggedIn, login, logout }}>
           <Menu />
           <Switch>
             <Route exact path='/' component={Home}>
             <Route exact path='/about' component={About}>
             <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact}>
           </Switch>
         </AuthContext.Provider>
       </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

To use this in for example the navbar you could call the useContext hook and pass the AuthContext as parameter:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthContext from '../../context/AuthContext';

function Navigation() {
  const { loggedIn, logout } = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <div>
      {!loggedIn && (
        <li>
          <a to="/auth">Login</a>
        </li>
      )}
      {loggedIn && (
        <>
          <li>
            <a to="/bookings">Bookings</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
          </li>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: This is awesome. Exactly what I wanted. But is there a working sample for this?

Comment: If you want to get the `loggedIn` state, just import the context pass it as parameter to useContext hook. I'll update the original answer.

Comment: I was about to last night. I'll try to get it work. It looks promising. Is useContext can only be used under a function component or class component? Because My parent component is using class.